# How change the input feactures when receive a focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

How I change the features of input, textarea and other elements that receive iteration, it's hard to explain but i have a picture that can explain how i want to do it[Here is picture that can explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk36M.jpg)

Comment: Are you talking about the outline on that `input` element?

Comment: see examples here https://codepen.io/b_atish/pen/dGxwRz/